# How can I help my fellow moderators be more welcoming to sincere questions and answers?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a trend of moderators that care more about the SO ethos than sincere inquiry.  A recent article explains this phenomenon very precisely. Does anyone have any tips for mitigating the deficiencies outlined in this article? In particular when relating to other people online at SO.

**Someone just tagged this as duplicate and referenced this post:**
[So Negative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

Which has nothing to do with my question. I asked how to socially interact to minimize the negative ethos. The irony is that that linked question is marked as closed.

[The Article](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.ryys9w9va)

Comment: And seriously, downvotes for this? Perhaps it has been discussed already, but this is a non-ranty attempt for input. This is so much better than most similar posts.

Comment: That article is not recent, and it's basically just a soporific soapbox of one user who doesn't get the scope/point/etc. of the site. It's also posted on Medium, which, let's be honest, doesn't cast it in a great light to begin with.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I followed the process but I still have an account so I'm using it while I have it.

Comment: "a trend of moderators that care more about the SO ethos than sincere inquiry" Can you elaborate on this? Specifically, what do you mean by "sincere inquiry"? Inquiry _into what_? What is the conflict between "car[ing] about [...] ethos" and this inquiry? The rest of us may not share your assumptions. Please consider [edit]ing to explain.

Comment: @hichris123 I don't see this question as any different from those questions on the main site that have readers follow links offsite to figure out what the substance of the question is.

Comment: @Josh Caswell, By ethos I mean the "character of the community" as I and many other have experienced which is very well outlined by the article. If I wish to use SO in the future, I'm going to help make it better or not use it at all.

Answer (score 10):

That article is frequently quoted on Reddit. I'll paste my reply to it as well:

> The classical Stack Overflow circlejerk is very present here, as is
>   tradition with posted blogs that talk about that site:
>
> - I found a question that I also have, but it's been closed!
> - I found a question that I also have, but it's closed as a duplicate that doesn't help me!
> - I found a question that asks how to do X, and they answered[sic] *"Why do you want to do that? The normal way to do that is Y!"*.
> - The moderators[sic] who close questions are power tripping jerks!
> - Noobs have the right to get answers too, and they should be treated more friendly because they don't know better!
> - I find *"[What is the best|Give me a list of] X"* a very useful question, but they don't!
> - It's all about the process for them autists, not the results that matter!
> - I tried to ask a question once, but it was downvoted! I'll never come back.
>
> With the usual zero links to evidence.
>
> If you make such claims, that could mean that you don't understand the
>   scope of the site. It is *not* a forum to help anyone to learn to
>   program, it's a repository of clear, concise, unique questions whose
>   answers help many others, asked and answered by professional or
>   enthusiast programmers.
>
> It is *hard* to ask a good question, even harder when you're
>   inexperienced. The ["How do I ask a good
>   question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page however is
>   not that long, and contains plenty of reading material that can even
>   help you solve your own problem, or ultimately, ask a question that
>   falls within the scope of what is allowed.

Comment: This does not answer my question, which is "How do I help fellow moderators?"

Comment: No, the entire premise to both the article and your question is false.